# Class Level Validation in Seam/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsf, richfaces, seam

I implemented a custom class level validator in my seam/hibernate application.  On my form I have `<s:validateAll>`.  This tag does not call the class level validation.

Related issue:
https://jira.jboss.org/browse/JBSEAM-1878

What is the best way for me to call this validation using Seam/JSF/RichFaces?

Answer (score 1):

Have you used the `validator` attribute? You have to use that together with either `s:validateAll` or `s:validate`

This is maybe not what you mean by hibernate class level validation, but at least it will work

For instance:

```
<h:inputText value="#{foo.bar}" validator="#{validator.checkFoo}" required="true">
  <s:validate/>
</h:inputText>
```

And validator

```
@Name("validator")
@Scope(ScopeType.EVENT)
@BypassInterceptors
public class Validator {
    public void checkFoo(FacesContext context, UIComponent toValidate, Object value) {
        //Do some check and if incorrect set this value
        ((UIInput) toValidate).setValid(false);
    }
}
```